# Versioning of script file that published on external domain by using ScriptTagHelper in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I use asp.net core 1.1.0. Main site published on a domain for example: site.com and all static files like css and js placed on a subdomain name static.site.com.

When use ScriptTagHelper as following, i expected that according to usage of asp-append-version attribute, version number append to js src but this not occur.

```
<script asp-append-version="true" src="http://static.site.com/js/site.js"></script>
```

I expected Something like this after rendered page

```
<script src="http://static.site.com/js/site.js?v=aNhFqVVmQXye2UDIUacX63ZaYbHi3fiDjhBhTA2aCCo"></script>
```

But result is:

```
<script src="http://static.site.com/js/site.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ScriptTagHelper does not append versions on files that are referenced via an absolute URI path. [Here's the code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/4a20c849cba358c43af69a8c739a8fecc33c8d67/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/Internal/FileVersionProvider.cs#L74-L78) responsible.